# Why do deleted exe System files come back?

Tags: windows-xp

I noticed on one computer running XP SP2 that when I delete some `exe` files (Examples: `spider.exe`, `spoolsv.exe`) from c:\Windows\System32 folder, that they came back. I thought it is a virus. So, I checked on another computers. One of them have the same. Is this normal?

Comment: What the hell did you do that for?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those files are critical parts of Windows XP and it's trying to rescue itself with [Windows File Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_File_Protection).

Answer (score 5):

For the well-being of your computer...

**Avoid modifying manually the contents of `C:\Windows`**

... unless you are very sure of what you are doing.

If you don't know, assume the files are Windows system files and leave them alone. Google a file name if you aren't sure.

Comment: The problem is that many people who mess things up there *believe* they know what they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

System files are in many ways similar to the voltage switch on your PSU: They are not to be tinkered with.

Comment: Whys that? How does this help his problem? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Kinokijuh's saying the same thing all the other good answers are saying, just in his own creative way Simon.

Answer (score 0):

`spoolsv.exe` is (usually) a print spooling service. `spider.exe` is part of the e-mail scraper service. Both are part of Windows XP, and although I've not heard of it could I guess can be regenerated on start-up.

If however, the `.exe` files are something else, then yes, you should be worried.

Why did you delete them anyway? Did you have evidence of their being dubious?

Sources: [File.net: spider.exe](http://www.file.net/process/spider.exe.html), [File.net: spoolsv.exe](http://www.file.net/process/spoolsv.exe.html).

These give other info like file sizes to help check authenticity.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its normal! If you want to delete a file from system 32, use the [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) application to do so! You can use an antivirus software to find out if a program is a virus or not, then use the delete feature in the antivirus software!

And don't make deductions for a virus based on your instincts! Usually viruses would be a hidden file!! If you find a suspicious file search for it on the net! And use some online scanners! Yeah its time consuming, but its worth it!